# Imprimir dados de um array de objetos PHP

Tags: php, array, mvc

Me bato um pouco com retorno do banco utilizando POO e MVC, e no caso estou trazendo os dados do banco onde a data cadastrada é igual a data atual, o problema é que criei um array de objetos para armazenar este retorno, e tenho que exibir os dados em outra página, que é onde provavelmente está ocorrendo o erro, segue o código

Código DAO:

```
 function buscaEventoPorDia($data, $idUsuario){
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare('select e.id_evento, u.nome_usuario, e.data_evento, e.descricao_evento, e.local_evento, e.prioridade_evento, e.organizador_evento from evento e inner join usuario u on e.usuario_id_usuario = u.id_usuario where e.data_evento = ? AND e.usuario_id_usuario = ?');

        $stm->bindValue(1, $data);
        $stm->bindValue(2, $idUsuario);
        $stm->execute();

        $max = $stm->rowCount();

        echo $max;

        //for ($i=0;$i < $max; $i++);

        $retornoEventos = [];       
        while ($linha=$stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $retornoEvento = new Evento();
            $retornoEvento->setId($linha['id_evento']);
            $retornoEvento->setUsuario($linha['nome_usuario']);
            $retornoEvento->setData($linha['data_evento']);
            $retornoEvento->setDescricao($linha['descricao_evento']);
            $retornoEvento->setLocal($linha['local_evento']);
            $retornoEvento->setPrioridade($linha['prioridade_evento']);
            $retornoEvento->setOrganizador($linha['organizador_evento']);
            $retornoEventos[] = $retornoEvento;
        }

            return $retornoEventos;`
}
```

Código Control:

```
$retornoEvento = $userDAO->buscaEventoPorDia($date, $id_user);//$evento)

        //var_dump($retornoEvento);

        echo"<tr>"; 
            echo"<td align='center'>".$retornoEvento->getId();"</td>";
            echo"<td align='center'>".$retornoEvento->getUsuario();"</td>";
            echo"<td align='center'>".$retornoEvento->getDescricao();"</td>";
            echo"<td align='center'>".$retornoEvento->getData();"</td>";
            echo"<td align='center'>".$retornoEvento->getPrioridade();"</td>";
            echo"<td align='center'>".$retornoEvento->getLocal();"</td>";
            echo"<td align='center'>".$retornoEvento->getOrganizador();"</td>";
            echo"</tr>";`
```

Gostaria de uma luz para quem sabe arrumar o laço for e criar o contador ou o que deve ser o correto a se fazer.

Desculpe-me a ignorância caso o padrão de pergunta esteja incorreto, ou a pergunta seja totalmente besta.
=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está faltando para você é iterar seu `array` `$retornoEvento`.

Para isto use um [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php) que fornece uma maneira fácil de fazer isto:

```
foreach ($retornoEvento as $obj) {
  echo $obj->getId();
  echo $obj->getUsuario();
  echo $obj->getDescricao();
  echo $obj->getData();
  echo $obj->getPrioridade();
  echo $obj->getLocal();
  echo $obj->getOrganizador();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, consegui arrumar aqui com a sua dica.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho de nada, qualquer coisa só perguntar!